# Odata Content Service V2 "Unable to build Template entry"

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, odata

I am getting error message while querying the Content Service V2 endpoint to access Component Presentations based on Template. The query looks like:

`http://<StagingContentServiceUrl>/client/v2/content.svc/Templates(PublicationId=PubId,ItemId=TemplateID)/ComponentPresentations?$format=json`

> {"error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Unable to build
>   Template entry: No resource was found for the requested item"}}}

I can see individual component presentation using query like:

`http://<StagingContentServiceUrl>/client/v2/content.svc/Components(ItemId=ComponentID,PublicationId=PubID)/ComponentPresentations?$format=json`

Anyone seen this error message before? I am wondering if this is because of any missing configuration..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic message Content service return when it doesn't found any component presentations published with specified template. We found that because of some caching implementation content service was not returning any result even after publishing content.